# Qemu virtio device not recongnized makes kernel panic

Tags: kernel, qemu, drive

I'm try to boot the linux with qemu-system-aarch64 with below options.

```
/home/levi/work/lisa-qemu/external/qemu/build/aarch64-softmmu/qemu-system-aarch64 -machine virt,gic-version=3 -m 2G -cpu max -drive file=/home/levi/work/lisa-qemu/build/VM-ubuntu.aarch64/ubuntu.aarch64.img.kernel-5.10.0+-2,if=none,id=drive0,cache=writeback -device virtio-blk,drive=drive0,bootindex=0 -drive file=flash0.img,format=raw,if=pflash -drive file=flash1.img,format=raw,if=pflash -smp cpus=2,cores=1 -kernel /home/levi/work/lisa-qemu/build/VM-ubuntu.aarch64/vmlinuz-5.10.0+-2 --initrd /home/levi/work/lisa-qemu/build/VM-ubuntu.aarch64/initrd.img-5.10.0+-2 -append "root=/dev/vda1 nokaslr console=ttyAMA0" -nographic
```

But, when when among boot, it couldn't find /dev/vda1. But only loop devices is exist, so it makes the kernel panic on mount_root.

```
[    1.468856] VFS: Cannot open root device "vda1" or unknown-block(0,0): error -6
```

I don't know how can i make kernel recognize my drive0 to make kernel boot...

flash.img0 is /usr/share/qemu-efi-aarch64QEMU_EFI.fd and flash.img1 is all zero images.

Answer (score 0):

This means your guest kernel does not have the necessary drivers configured into it to support virtio. The [QEMU documentation for the virt board](https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/system/arm/virt.html#linux-guest-kernel-configuration) suggests that some config options you should make sure you have enabled in your kernel are:

```
CONFIG_PCI=y
CONFIG_VIRTIO_PCI=y
CONFIG_PCI_HOST_GENERIC=y
```

and for virtio-gpu-pci graphics:

```
CONFIG_DRM=y
CONFIG_DRM_VIRTIO_GPU=y
```

Plus make sure you have all the options for the specific virtio backends you want (in this case, the virtio block device).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But options mentioned above already configured and kernel build properly.

Comment: It would be helpful to quote more than just the single line of the log. Usually the run-up to that line has information that sheds more light on why the kernel couldn't open the root filesystem.

Comment: What I saw is that the /dev/vda1 isn't found when found the device. it just have loop devices not /dev/vda. What i question is that why /dev/vda1 isn't appear on that thou I used -device and -drive options.

Comment: When I say "quote more than just the single line of the log", I mean "quote more of the log", not "tell me what your interpretation of the log information is"... If /dev/vda isn't in the list, then it very likely means your kernel is still missing some config options.